# Repeatedly storing JSON logs as files with Go and ensuring unique filenames

Tags: json, go

A bit of a newcomer to Go, and I'm effectively receiving a small (~1KB) JSON file from an API repeatedly that is effectively a log, and I want to keep each one of these files.

I'm thinking just storing each JSON block as a unique file (in lieu of using a database, which seems unnecessary) in a specific directory.

First off, is this an okay idea? There could be potentially a few hundred per day.

More importantly, how do I ensure uniqueness across filenames? Obviously I can't just save each one as `log.json` and call it a day, as there would be conflicts. How would I ensure uniqueness?

Comment: Have you considered storing the JSON in NoSQL storage? Writing all those file to disk seems a bit wasteful (and error-prone IMO)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whether it's agood idea or not is subjective, but you can use [`ioutil.TempFile`](https://golang.org/pkg/io/ioutil/#TempFile) to ensure you have unique filenames. `TempFile` will append a guaranteed unique suffix to the file prefix you choose.

```
f, err := ioutil.TempFile(storeDirectory, fileName)
```

Comment: But what if I don't want the file to be temporary?

Comment: It's not temporary in that it will auto delete at some point in the future. You have to explicitly delete it when you're done with it `os.Remove(f.Name())` but it will stay otherwise.

Comment: @DougSmith: the only other time it would be temporary in some sense, is if you don't specify a directory and the file is put into an ephemeral temp dir by default, i.e. some systems may periodically clean out `$TMPDIR`.